# Automating tasks on more than one SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, automation, database-restore

We host multiple SQL Server 2008 databases provided by another group. Every so often, they provide a backup of a new version of one of the databases, and we run through a routine of deleting the old one, restoring the new one, and then going into the newly restored database and adding an existing SQL login as a user in that database and assigning it a standard role that exists in all of these databases.

The routine is the same, except that each database has a different name and different logical and OS names for its data and log files. My inclination was to set up an auxiliary database with a table defining the set of names associated with each database, and then create a stored procedure accepting the name of the database to be replaced and the name of the backup file as parameters. The SP would look up the associated logical and OS file names and then do the work.

This would require building the commands as strings and then exec'ing them, which is fine. However, the stored procedure, after restoring a database, would then have to USE it before it would be able to add the SQL login to the database as a user and assign it to the database role. A stored procedure can't do this.

What alternative is there for creating an automated procedure with the pieces filled in dynamically and that can operate cross-database like this?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution.

1. Create a job to do the work, specifying that the job should be run out of the master database, and defining one Transact-SQL step for it that contains the code to be executed.
2. In a utility database created just for the purpose of hosting objects to be used by the job, create a table meant to contain at most one row, whose data will be the parameters for the job.
3. In that database, create a stored procedure that can be called with the parameters that should be stored for use by the job (including the name of the database to be replaced). The SP should validate the parameters, report any errors, and, if successful, write them to the parameter table and start the job using msdb..sp_start_job.
4. In the job, for any statement where the job needs to reference the database to be replaced, build the statement as a string and EXECUTE it.
5. For any statement that needs to be run in the database that's been re-created, doubly-quote the statement to use as an argument for the instance of sp_executesql IN THAT DATABASE, and use EXECUTE to run the whole thing:

   SET @statement = @dbName + '..sp_executesql ''[statement to execute in database @dbName]''';

   EXEC (@statement);
6. Configure the job to write output to a log file.